# Background Bluetooth Device Discovery Error with flutter_bluetooth_serial and flutter_blue

Tags: flutter, background-process, background-task, flutter-background

I am currently working on a Flutter application that involves Bluetooth device discovery in the background. To achieve this, I have tried using the flutter_bluetooth_serial package in combination with flutter_background_service. However, I encountered the error message "Bluetooth is not available" when attempting to discover devices in the background.

I tried using the flutter_bluetooth_serial and flutter_blue package, which produced the same error "Bluetooth is not available". However, when I switched to the flutter_blue_plus package, it successfully scanned devices in the background. But my application relies on serial Bluetooth communication.

I would like to understand why I am encountering this error with flutter_bluetooth_serial and flutter_blue and how I can resolve it?

If you have any insights, tips, or solutions for background Bluetooth device discovery with these packages, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this on android? if so you need some permissions on the manifest

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar scenario, but after I switched on the Device' location/GPS, Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dokumentation of flutter_blue_plus they wrote that many Devices arent supported in the classical flutter_blue plugin.

Maybee this was the case with the devices you tried to Scann.

Best of luck champ.

> https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue

speakers, headphones, mice, keyboards, gamepads, Arduino HC-05 & HC-06, and more are not supported. These all use Bluetooth Classic.

Also, iBeacons are not supported on iOS. Apple requires you to use CoreLocation